# Handling css and Javascript in urlrewriting

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have implimented url rewriting in my asp.net application but when the request is made for the page at which I had implimented url rewriting it is not taking the CSS and javascript which I had given at top of my page.

Comment: Do you have any code examples to show?

Comment: My guess would e that your rewriting rules make the paths you made to those files invalid.

Comment: i am not understanding what happens does i have to write my css and js path in rewriting rules

Comment: I think, it is path of CSS can you send the HTML out put for the css file... if this is case, try using "~" for every url in ASPX file or start the url with "/" in the HTML which starts the path from domain.